# Spoke length with NOVATEC GOLD PISTA hubs and H PLUS SON SL42 rims

Tags: hub, rims, single-speed, spokes

I have bought the NOVATEC GOLD PISTA hubs (http://novatecusa.net/project/a166sbt-rh/) and the H PLUS SON SL42 rims (http://hplusson.com/products/SL42) with 32 spokes.
Someone know how does long I must buy the spokes?

Thanks

Comment: Google for "spoke length calculator".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the right spoke length requires some fairly accurate measurements and is dependent on the pattern that you want to lace the wheels (radial, 2x, 3x, 4x) and is further complicated in the rear as you have drive-side and non-drive side (possibly not an issue with the single-speed/fixie hubs you have).

Most bike shops are familiar with spoke length calculators and the measurements that need to be put in them (and may have access to calculators that allow them to enter the components instead of measurements). If you buy/order the spokes from the LBS, chances are they will help you determine the correct size.

Happy Riding.